# If $A$ is dense in $S$ and $S$ is dense in $T$ , then $A$ is dense in $T$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In a metric space $M$, if the subsets satisfy $A \subseteq S \subseteq \bar A$ where $\bar A$ refers to the closure of $A$, then $A$ is said to be dense in $S$. If If A is dense in S and S is dense in T , show that then A is dense in T.

**Attempt:** Given that $A$ is dense in $S \implies A \subseteq S \subseteq \bar A$

and $S$ is dense in $T \implies S \subseteq T \subseteq \bar S$.

We need to prove that $S \implies A \subseteq S \subseteq T \subseteq  \bar A$.

Let us suppose that $A \subseteq S \subseteq  \bar A \subseteq T \subseteq \bar S 
\quad\ldots(1)$.

Then it can be inferred that $A $ is dense in $S$, $S$ is dense in $\bar A$, $S$ is dense in $T$.

Hence, $\bar A$ might contain some accumulations points of $S$ . $T$ might also contain some accumulation points of $S$.

How do I proceed to bring about a contradiction to assumption $(1)$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $A⊆S⊆T\subseteq\bar S⊆\bar{\bar A}=\bar A$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, isn't that what we have to prove?

Comment: Which inclusion is unclear?

Comment: The inclusion : $T \subseteq  \bar S \subseteq \bar A$ ..

Comment: Since $S⊆\bar A$, taking the closure on both sides gives $\bar S⊆\bar{\bar A}$. But the closure of the closure of $A$ is the same as the closure of $A$. So the short proof of your statement assumes you are already familiar with these properties.

Comment: If $S \subseteq \bar A$, then the set of limit points of $S$ may/ may not be contained in $\bar A$. Hence, will the relation $\bar S \subseteq \bar A$ always hold?

Comment: Yes, this holds in every topological space.

Comment: But, by definition of $\bar A = A \cup A'.$ then :if  $S \subseteq \bar A $, then $\bar A \subseteq \bar S$ .I am actually taking an introductory course in Real Analysis from Apostol. In the book, this question is directly asked in the exercises

Comment: @StefanHamcke I got it. Thank you for your comments :-)

Comment: For the record you don't use any metric space properties in this theorem, jus topological spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are given $A\subset S\subset\bar A$ and $S\subset T\subset\bar S$, and you must show $A\subset T\subset\bar A$.

From the hypotheses, you have $A\subset S$ and $S\subset T$, so $\boxed{A\subset T}$.

From the hypotheses, $T\subset\bar S$; you also have from the hypotheses that $S\subset\bar A$, so $\bar S\subset\overline{(\bar A)} = \bar A$. Thus $\boxed{T\subset\bar A}$.

The boxed conclusions above demonstrate that $\boxed{A\subset T\subset\bar A}$ as required. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

Remember that $S\subset \bar{A}$ implies $\bar{S}\subset\bar{A}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

(Note: Someone in comments below dislikes this answer because it assumes the space is metrizable.  But the question explicitly said it is a metric space.)

Let $t$ be a point in $T$ and let $\varepsilon>0$.  It suffices to show the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ about $t$ contains at least one point of $A$.  Since $S$ is dense in $T$, that ball contains at least one point $s$ of $S$.  Now let $\eta=\varepsilon-d(t,s)>0$. Then the ball of radius $\eta$ about $s$ must contain some point $a$ in $A$.  Now use the triangle inequality to show that $d(t,a)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :-)

Comment: I like this because it seems (to me) more direct than the proof based on the subset/closure definition of density.

Comment: @KyleStrand I don't like this because it assumes a metrizable space. And while direct and "elementary", it doesn't catch the points at all, IMHO.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Unless, I'm missing something, you seem to be assuming that every point of $T$ needs to be an accumulation point of $A$. This needn't be the case if $T$ contains isolated points (which, of course, would also have to belong to $A$). Doesn't this fail if $t$ is such a point? The result is a general topological fact, and doesn't require metrizability at all.

Comment: @MPW : OK, I've done a bit of editing.

Comment: @tohecz : The question explicitly said it was a metric space!

Comment: @tohecz What do you mean by "doesn't catch the points at all"?

Comment: This is a nice short answer--so +1 for you. Still, I'm a big fan of minimal use of hypotheses, especially if you can get away with omitting some of them. For me, the reward there is that you can actually prove a stronger statement.

Comment: @KyleStrand The point is that you first derive that $S\subset \bar A$ implies $\bar S\subset \bar A$, which is a nice, simple and completely general statement, and is somehow the core of the proof. And now, you only use this very general statement, rather than fiddling with complicated stuff as $\epsilon-d(t,s)$, from which, no true idea can be observed.

Comment: @tohecz $\epsilon - d(t,s)$ may *look* complicated, but the very simple intuition behind the proof is that points in $T$ are "close to" points in $A$ because they're also "close to" points in $S$, and points in $S$ are "close to" points in $A$. I.e., in metric spaces, "closeness" is transitive. This is easy to visualize and reason about. I do like the simplicity and generality of the $S \bar \subseteq A \bar$ statement, and I appreciate that the proof works in non-metrizable topological spaces, but I also like being able to visualize statements about metric spaces.

Comment: ...any idea why the subset statement isn't rendered in that last comment?

Comment: @KyleStrand Because `\bar` goes _before_ `A`, not after that. There's actually a red nothing after the 2nd `\bar` showing that an argument is missing. The correct thingy is: `$\bar S \subseteq \bar A$`. And I get your point. Just somehow, you can change balls to "bubbles" (arbitrarily shaped open sets) and it's the same, still keeping the idea behind. And you can even draw it like that without any need of letters -- isn't that cool? :)

Comment: @tohecz: You inability to "observe" any "true idea" in $\varepsilon-d(t,s)$ is only your inability. A simple idea is there: Draw the picture of the ball of radius $\varepsilon$, with $t$ at its center and $s$ somewhere in the interior. The quantity $\varepsilon-d(t,s)$ would be the distance from $s$ to the boundary of that ball, if we assumed a Euclidean space, and is the upper bound, over all metric spaces, of the distance a point can be from $s$ without leaving that ball.  Draw the ball of that radius about $s$ and it will be just small enough to guarantee that it is inside that larger ball.